# Is there a way to process Async process response as they get completed in Spring Boot micro services?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, microservices

Suppose we have 5 different service calls in a single function and all are asynchronous, I want to process each of them as they get completed.

As example these are 3 different functions available in 3 different classes

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Actor> lookForId(String id) throws InterruptedException {
    LOG.info("Looking up Movie ID: {}", Id);
    String url = "http://localhost:7073/data/" + id;
    Actor results = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Actors.class);
    // Artificial delay of 1s for demonstration purposes
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results);
}

@Async
public CompletableFuture<Singer> lookForId(String id) throws InterruptedException {
    LOG.info("Looking up Movie ID: {}", id);
    String url = "http://localhost:7075/data/" + id;
    Singer results = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Singer.class);
    // Artificial delay of 1s for demonstration purposes
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results);
}

@Async
public CompletableFuture<Writer> lookForId(String id) throws InterruptedException {
    LOG.info("Looking up Movie ID: {}", id);
    String url = "http://localhost:7078/data/" + id;
    Writer results = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Writer.class);
    // Artificial delay of 1s for demonstration purposes
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results);
}
```

And the function invoking them is like below code

```
public String getResp() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    CompletableFuture<Actor> page1 = actorAsyncService.lookForId("0");
    CompletableFuture<Singer> page2 = singerAsyncService.lookForId("2");
    CompletableFuture<Writer> page3 = singerAsyncService.lookForId("4");
    String respStr = page1.get() + "||" + page2.get() + "||" + page3.get() ;
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>> Elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    System.out.println("respStr : " + respStr);
    return respStr;
}
```

Here the process waits for each of the process to complete and then send back the response but I want in a way that once **Any of the process is completed** then service should return the response to calling function But also should be able to process the response provided by other service calls when rest of the process complete or terminate or give error response.

For e.g. if page2 process completes then response of that process returned to calling function but still the function should be able to process the response coming from page1 & page2 when the process is completed.

Answer (score 0):

`CompletableFuture.anyOf()` returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when any of the given CompletableFutures complete, with the same result.

Here is my example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture<String> task1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("task 1 finished");
            return "task 1";
        });

        CompletableFuture<String> task2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("task 2 finished");
            return "task 2";
        });

        CompletableFuture<String> task3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("task 3 finished");
            return "task 3";
        });
        CompletableFuture<Object> future = CompletableFuture.anyOf(task1, task2, task3);
        String result = (String)future.get();
        System.out.println(result);

        task1.join();
        task2.join();
        task3.join();
    }
```

And the output is:

```
task 1 finished
task 1
task 2 finished
task 3 finished
```

Comment: When we do join() or get() on **CompletableFuture** object then it will wait for all the process to complete but I want to return the response to calling function after returning the response the process is getting closed and rest of the response are not getting processed. I want to return the response to calling function then still be able to process the upcoming response from remaining response that was not available till the time i was returning the response.